# Equally divide the div and center them

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

html code:

```
<body>    
    <div id="grid-main_content">
        <div class="block ">
            <div class="column column-1">
                <p>Esse ingeniis instituendarum...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="block">
            <div class="column column-2">
                <p>Quis voluptate o comprehenderit non fugiat ullamco..</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-2">
                <p>Irure an arbitror de appellat fugiat offendit,..</p>
            </div>
            <span class="clear-both"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="block">
            <div class="column column-3">
                <p>Cernantur est possumus,..</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-3">
                <p>Multos quamquam deserunt ea minim sed consequat,..</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-3">
                <p>Eiusmod illum mandaremus quo appellat...</p>
            </div>
            <span class="clear-both"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="block">
            <div class="column column-4">
                <p>Duis arbitror sed dolor sint...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-4">
                <p>Eram expetendis doctrina ut offendit ipsum et deserunt familiaritatem,..</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-4">
                <p>Cupidatat aut elit appellat...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-4">
                <p>Eu irure summis...</p>
            </div>
            <span class="clear-both"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.block {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
}

.column {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.column-1 {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
}

.column-2 {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
}

.column-3 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
}

.column-4 {
    background: red;
    width: 23%;
    float: left;
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, all of the contents of  each blocks are not equal in length and are not centered because I want the block (columns) to be responsive to the width. How can I equally divide them into column-1 having full width, column-2 having 1/2 of the width, column-3 having 1/3 of the width and column-4 with a width of 1/4 width? And be centered horizontally.

Comment: use <table> instead?

Comment: What have you tried? Tables will do this as simon said, flexbox will also as well (with even more ease), various margin/padding hacks, and several other concoctions. Just google "equal cloumn height" and there's tonnes of content. In addition to this, try putting your code in a Snippet. It does not reproduce the result depicted.

Comment: @simon Yes that will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css:

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;
}
*{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.block {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.column {
    padding: 5px;
}

.column-1 {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
}

.column-2 {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.column-3 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 33.333%;
    float: left;
}

.column-4 {
    background: red;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

js:

```
$(function(){
            equalHeight();
        });
        $(window).resize(function(){
            equalHeight();
        });
        function equalHeight(){
            var maxHeight = 0;
            $(".column-4").each(function(){
               if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
            });
            $(".column-4").height(maxHeight);

            $(".column-3").each(function(){
               if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
            });
            $(".column-3").height(maxHeight);

            $(".column-2").each(function(){
               if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
            });
            $(".column-2").height(maxHeight);

        }
```

find **[fiddle dmeo](http://jsfiddle.net/18er3xzo/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

`flexbox` can do that.

With just this:

```
.block {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex:1;
}
```

Suppport is IE10 and up.

```css
.block {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  flex:1;
}

.column-1 {
    background: lightblue;
}

.column-2 {
    background: lightgreen;
}

.column-3 {
    background: yellow;
}

.column-4 {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>    
    <div id="grid-main_content">
        <div class="block ">
            <div class="column column-1">
                <p>Esse ingeniis instituendarum...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="block">
            <div class="column column-2">
                <p>Quis voluptate o comprehenderit non fugiat ullamco..</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-2">
                <p>Irure an arbitror de appellat fugiat offendit,..</p>
            </div>
    
        </div>

        <div class="block">
            <div class="column column-3">
                <p>Cernantur est possumus,..</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-3">
                <p>Multos quamquam deserunt ea minim sed consequat,..</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-3">
                <p>Eiusmod illum mandaremus quo appellat...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="block">
            <div class="column column-4">
                <p>Duis arbitror sed dolor sint...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-4">
                <p>Eram expetendis doctrina ut offendit ipsum et deserunt familiaritatem,..</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-4">
                <p>Cupidatat aut elit appellat...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-4">
                <p>Eu irure summis...</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/gx9hfeLq/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/gx9hfeLq/) that helps you with setting equal widths. It uses border-box so you won't have your boxes bumping to the next line when you use exactly half (50%), third (33.3%) etc. The padding takes up space *inside* the boxes making them fit and stretch 100% across:

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
```